# FULLPAGE.JS Get .active slide and update the number on each new slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, counter, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get the

```
current slide / total slides
```

on Fullpage.js and get the current slide updated everytime the slide changes.

I'm a total newbie on Javascript and I'm trying to work around this code. The numbers appear but they do not update every slide change.

```
$(function() {

var sections = $('.section');
updateCurrentIndex(); //on document.ready and on each slidechange
function updateCurrentIndex() {
sections.each(function() {
  var section = $(this),
    sectionSlides = section.find('.slide'),
    totalItems = sectionSlides.length,
    currentIndex = sectionSlides.filter('.active').index() + 1,
    numContainer = section.find('.num'); //assuming you have numContainers in every section

  numContainer.html("0" + currentIndex + ' / ' + totalItems);
});
}
});
```

Any help would be greatly apprciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/66/

Answer (score 3):

You should be makeing use of the fullPage.js callbacks, such as `onSlideLeave` or [`afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex).

For example:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
     anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

     afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
        var loadedSlide = $(this);
        var totalItems = loadedSlide.siblings().length;
        var numContainer = loadedSlide.closest('.fp-section').find('.num');
        numContainer.html("0" + slideIndex + ' / ' + totalItems);
    }
});
```

### Update Dec 2021 - fullpage.js v3

This is much easier now with the new methods `getActiveSlide` and `getActiveSection` that fullPage.js provides. See [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#methods) for more info.

[Codepen online](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/OJxXreQ)

```js
new fullpage("#fullpage", {
  sectionsColor: ["yellow", "orange", "#C0C0C0", "#ADD8E6"],
  anchors: ["firstPage", "secondPage", "thirdPage", "fourthPage", "lastPage"],
  slidesNavigation: true,
  afterSlideLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
    setCounter();
  },
  afterRender: function(){
    setCounter();
  }
});

function setCounter(){
    var sectionItem = fullpage_api.getActiveSection().item;
    var numSlides = sectionItem.querySelectorAll(".fp-slide").length;
    var currentSlideWrapper = document.querySelector(".counter");
    var slideNumber = fullpage_api.getActiveSlide().index + 1;
    currentSlideWrapper.innerHTML = "0" + slideNumber + " / " + numSlides;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro, I've just updated my Fiddle and it looks like it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/68/

Comment: The .num was in the section and not in the slide as I though it was. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/69/ Updated the answer too.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alvaro, you made my day!

Just a quick one, what if the .num is outside #fullpage? Is there an easy way to find and update it?

Comment: Yeah, just change the selector: `loadedSlide.closest('.fp-section').find('.num');`. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue so others can know it.

Comment: the only problem I still have is that the counter doesn't refresh / restart on section change.

Comment: Apply the same logic but with the `onLeave` or `afterSectionLoad` callbacks... can't be bothered to do it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm here at the moment and I'm sure very close to the solution.
The problem, still, is that if you go up to the previous .section the counter will always be 01 / XX instead of showing the number of the actual .active slide.

```
afterLoad: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
  var loadedSlide = $(this);
  var slideIndex = find(".fp-slide .active") + 1;
  var totalItems = loadedSlide.closest(".fp-section").find(".fp-slide").length;
  var numContainer = loadedSlide.closest(document).find(".num");
  numContainer.html("0" + slideIndex + " / " + "0" + totalItems);
},
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
  var section = $(this),
    sectionSlides = section.find(".slide"),
    totalItems = sectionSlides.length,
    currentIndex = sectionSlides.filter(".fp-slide .active").length + 1,
    numContainer = section.closest(document).find(".num");
  numContainer.html("0" + currentIndex + ' / ' + "0" + totalItems);
}
})
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/71/